# Deploying Node app to Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, hapi.js

I am having trouble deploying an app to Heroku. When my server starts, it crashes immediately with no error message, so I have nothing to go off. I am using Hapi, and everything runs fine locally.

This is my src/index.js:

```
const Hapi = require('hapi')
const routes = require('./routes')

const server = new Hapi.Server()
const connectionOptions = {
  host: process.env.HOST_NAME,
  port: process.env.PORT || 8080
}

server.connection(connectionOptions)
console.log('SERVER CONNECTION')
routes({ server })
```

These are the Heroku logs:

```
2017-08-16T20:23:55.716723+00:00 app[web.1]: > node ./src/index.js
2017-08-16T20:23:56.714915+00:00 app[web.1]: Server started at: http://hashtag-news-api-dev.herokuapp.com:45709
2017-08-16T20:23:56.677341+00:00 app[web.1]: SERVER CONNECTION
2017-08-16T20:23:56.809918+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
2017-08-16T20:23:56.816328+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

Am I missing something? I thought I had everything in place to get going on Heroku

Answer (score 0):

Setting `HOST_NAME` to `'0.0.0.0'` worked.